# Text position within a frame - Python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to position my text in the center of my GUI. When the GUI window expands the text needs to stay centered.

I'm also trying to keep the text aligned with each other.
I'm succeeding when I'm putting in empty Label but this isn't very elegant and when I make my GUI full screen it isn't centered anymore.

Any suggestions?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import csv


master = Tk()
master.option_add("*Font", "{Bodoni MT} 8")

content = ttk.Frame(master, padding=(12, 12, 12, 12))
frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=300, height=100)
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=(N, E, W))
text = Text(content, height=8, width=13)
text.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=(N, S, E, W))


v1surface = StringVar()
v2surface = StringVar()
v1tournament = StringVar()
v2tournament = StringVar()

empty_row = Label(frame).grid(column=1, padx=100, sticky=(N, E, W))
surface_title = Label(frame, text="Surface", font="{Bodoni MT} 12 bold underline").grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
surface_selection = Label(frame, text="Select Surface:").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w')
a_surface = Label(frame, text="Service Points Win %:").grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')
aa_surface = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v1surface, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=3, column=3)
b_surface = Label(frame, text="Return Points Win %: ").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='w')
bb_surface = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v2surface, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=4, column=3)


tournament_title = Label(frame, text="Tournament", font="{Bodoni MT} 12 bold underline")\
    .grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=2)
tournament_selection = Label(frame, text="Select Tournament:").grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='w')
a_tournament = Label(frame, text="Service Points Win %:").grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='w')
aa_tournament = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v1tournament, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=3, column=6)
b_tournament = Label(frame, text="Return Points Win %: ").grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='w')
bb_tournament = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v2tournament, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=4, column=6)



run = ttk.Button(content, text='Run')
run.grid(column=4, row=3)
cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Cancel", command=master.destroy)
cancel.grid(column=5, row=3)

master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
content.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

master.geometry("1000x500+100+100")
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which text do you want centered? I see lots of labels. Do you want the entry widgets centered as well?  Your description is very vague.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I want all the Labels and Entry widgets in 'frame' centered

Comment: Do you want the frame that they are in centered as well? Or do you want the frame at the top and the widgets inside centered in the frame?

Comment: I want the frame to stay like it is, so the widgets need to be centered in the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want.

One common solution when using `grid` is to leave one column (and/or row) empty on each side of your main content. Give these columns or rows a weight. The visual result is that everything inside of those empty columsn remains centered because the edges take up all of the extra space. This can get complex, though, if you have other columns that also have weight.

An arguably better solution is to place all of the things you want treated as a group into a frame, and then all you have to worry about is centering that one frame. In fact, this is really the exact reason why the `Frame` widget exists -- to allow you to group related widgets and treat them as a single object as far as layout is concerned.

At the end of this answer is an example of the latter technique. In this case it uses `place` to center the frame since it has options that make this very simple. You could use `pack` or `grid` with appropriate options if you prefer.

In the example I also grouped all of the layout commands together. In my experience it makes it much easier to visualize, and much easier to maintain your code over time. The exact layout isn't precisely how I would do it, because I tried to touch as little of your code as I could.

Notice that I added one new widget, `inner_frame`, and removed one widget, `empty_row`. I then centered the inner frame inside the other frame (the one named `frame`). Finally, I set the parent of all of the labels and entries to be the inner frame.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import csv

master = Tk()
master.option_add("*Font", "{Bodoni MT} 8")

content = ttk.Frame(master, padding=(12, 12, 12, 12), borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=300, height=100)
text = Text(content, height=8, width=13)


v1surface = StringVar()
v2surface = StringVar()
v1tournament = StringVar()
v2tournament = StringVar()

inner_frame = Frame(frame)

surface_title = Label(inner_frame, text="Surface", font="{Bodoni MT} 12 bold underline")
surface_selection = Label(inner_frame, text="Select Surface:")
a_surface = Label(inner_frame, text="Service Points Win %:")
aa_surface = Entry(inner_frame, text="value", textvariable=v1surface, justify='center', width=10)
b_surface = Label(inner_frame, text="Return Points Win %: ")
bb_surface = Entry(inner_frame, text="value", textvariable=v2surface, justify='center', width=10)

tournament_title = Label(inner_frame, text="Tournament", font="{Bodoni MT} 12 bold underline")\
    .grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=2)
tournament_selection = Label(inner_frame, text="Select Tournament:").grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='w')
a_tournament = Label(inner_frame, text="Service Points Win %:").grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='w')
aa_tournament = Entry(inner_frame, text="value", textvariable=v1tournament, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=3, column=6)
b_tournament = Label(inner_frame, text="Return Points Win %: ").grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='w')
bb_tournament = Entry(inner_frame, text="value", textvariable=v2tournament, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=4, column=6)

run = ttk.Button(content, text='Run')
cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Cancel", command=master.destroy)

# main layout
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=(N, E, W))
text.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
run.grid(column=4, row=3)
cancel.grid(column=5, row=3)

# inner frame, used for centering
inner_frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

# widgets in the inner frame
surface_title.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)
surface_selection.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w')
a_surface.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')
aa_surface.grid(row=3, column=3)
b_surface.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='w')
bb_surface.grid(row=4, column=3)

master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
content.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

master.geometry("1000x500+100+100")
master.mainloop()
```